# readonly fields initialization order

Tags: c#

I found a class similar to the follow one:

```
class Controller
{
    private readonly IDataContext _myContext = new DataContext("connectionstring");

    public Controller(IDataContext context){
        _myContext = context;
    }
}
```

Given instances are created as bellow:

```
var controller = new Controller(new DataContext("anotherconnectionstring"));
```

What I would like to know is which will be the final instance assigned to _myContext field? The one passed as an argument or the one used as RHS in the declaration?

Comment: have you tried to see what the compiler does?

Comment: You are right Daniel, sadly I am not in Windows and I don´t have mono neither. I am just browsing code from an online repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All fields which are initialized explicitly in a class definition are moved into the default class/type constructor which will be called before any other explicitly defined parametrized constructor. So final value willl be a value you are passing in custom constructor.

[MSDN, Fields (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)

> Fields are initialized immediately before the constructor for the
>   object instance is called. If the constructor assigns the value of a
>   field, it will overwrite any value given during field declaration.